# Migration to heroku undefined when adding to user model (devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, devise

I've added an 'area' attribute to my user model (I am using devise).  This migration works on localhost and I have run heroku rake db:migrate - when I've pushed to heroku it is giving an error message on the sign up page

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `area' for #<User:0x00000006589520>)
```

My signup view has:

```
<%= f.input :area, label: "Specialty" %>
```

db migration:

```
class AddAreaColumnToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :area, :string
  end
end
```

Have I missed out some part of the heroku migration?

Comment: did you try `heroku restart` after the migration?

Comment: no problem, just googled it :)

Comment: thanks - sorry, I couldn't find the answer. thank you.

Comment: yeah, no problem, just googled `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `